# Check geolocation permission status using typescript | Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

Using javascript I can check the user geolocation permission status is allow or block. For the same thing is it possible to find the geolocation using Angular 4 typescript. Or shall I use the same javascript code. I want to Integrate this stuff in Ionic framework also

javascript code shown below

```
navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function(PermissionStatus) {
    if(PermissionStatus.state == 'granted'){
          //allowed
    }else{
         //denied
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you try using your code in Ionic?

Comment: No, i didn't try in my ionic code. I

Comment: Just try it in your project and see it works

Comment: @Rijo Are you expecting a angular's in build geo module?